# Singular possessive to stand for a finite collective of individuals?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

For context, this is taken from an academic study analysing qualitative data from a finite number of interviewees. In the conclusion, the writer asserts the following:

> Collectively, the **interviewee's insights** undermine the notion that...

Here, he means the insights of each individual interviewee taken collectively.

Initially, I saw this as a simple error that should read 'interviewees'' instead.

However, if he had written, 'Collectively, **each** interviewee's insights...' or, 'Collectively, the insights **of the interviewee**...', that would make sense to me.

Therefore, is the original sentence grammatically justifiable? Can a singular possessive stand for a finite collective of individuals in this instance?

Comment: I don't think the word "collectively" is a good collocation with a word representing an individual.  An individual doesn't do something collectively.  I would not have used the apostrophe and would have kept the plural reference.

Comment: 'Considering these test cases collectively, it becomes clear that the patient's needs must come first'...?

Comment: Why do you think "the insights of the interviewee" would refer to multiple interviewees?  That seems as unclear (or wrong) as the original.  Are you considering "the interviewee" to be a generic noun?  That would be quite unusual.  This looks like a spelling error to me ("interviewee's" instead of the intended "interviewees'")

Comment: *Collectively, the interviewee insights undermine the notion that...* (where *interviewee* is an attributive noun functioning as an adjective).

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat Not often used as an attributive noun; 'the collective insights of the interviewees' sounds much more idiomatic.